# Will this update my sql information?

Tags: php, mysql

Stupid title I know.  I have this:

```
$x = array_keys($_POST);
foreach($x as $y) {

 $query = "UPDATE * FROM  events (PromotionalTimeLine = "$_POST[$y]" WHERE EventID='$y'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  print_r($result);

}
```

I need to update only the `PromotionalTimeLine` cell for specific rows with `$y` as their `EventID`.  Will this do that?

Comment: Just curious, you have written that query using random sql keywords?

Comment: Yes just totally random...thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

No, You have mysql syntax error with update query.

```
$query = "UPDATE events 
          SET PromotionalTimeLine = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$y])."' 
          WHERE EventID='".$y."'";
```

Comment: Last $y is not filtered but +1'ed anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You string concatenation has some problems. It should be

```
$query = "UPDATE events SET PromotionalTimeLine = '" .$_POST[$y]. "' WHERE EventID='".$y."'";
```

And also you have not sanitized your input, Which I'd advise you to do so the cose is not vulnerable to SQL injection or similar attacks. Here is an detailed post on sanitizing input - [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: @Daric What error in this query, are u saying about mysql_real_escape_string function ?

Comment: @J.J. He posted the comment when i was editing the answer. Realized I had missed an error after posting only.

Answer (score -1):

Incidentally, none of the other answers worked for me.  This worked though:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE events 
          SET PromotionalTimeLine = '$_POST[$y]'
          WHERE EventID='$y' ");
```

Comment: ... and opens up a big hole for SQL injections.

Comment: I'm not talking about the escaping, I'm talking about the format of all the above answers did not work for me. I don't know enough about this to know why, but they didn't work and this does.